# Custom Vector Types

Tags: c++, class, vector, lnk

Are there any restrictions on creating vectors with custom classes? Recently, my compiler has been sending a 'LNK1120' warning whenever I attempt the statement:

```
vector<Team> teamList;
```

If this is illegal, is there a workaround that would allow me to store/organize a group of these instances? Thanks.

Comment: LNK112 is useless; what does the LNK2001 that comes before it say?

Comment: By the way, you could say you are using Visual Studio, and what version

Comment: Add source for Team class. You probably did not implement all Team class functions.

Answer (score 1):

[LNK2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx) followed by [LNK1120](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z98k84c3.aspx) are linkers error. It isn't (inherently) related to your custom vector type.

Looking at your code, I can see two possible reasons here :

1. you just forgot using `std::vector` or `using namespace std;` and the linker can't find what you mean by `vector`
2. the piece of code above isn't linked to the object containing the class `Team`

And of course, creating a `vector` with custom classes isn't illegal at all.

Answer (score 0):

LNK1120 - unresolved externals?

We need more source code and linker output.